# How to pass variable to http client in my script in react.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a web-app with a webchat as a script which is connected to an AI-Service via URL. The URL is hardcode in my client, now I want to implement a variable on my webchat with which an user can pass his own URL to the client to connect to any service. My problem is, that I dont know how I can pass a variable value to my script. When I inspect the web-app I can see that the component of the web-app gets the new URL but when I print the variable of the script it says "undefined". How do I have to proceed here?

Client needs the URL but prints "undefined" this is a component of my script

```
export class APIClient {
  constructor(serviceURL) {

    const serviceURL = widget.get("serviceURL");

 
    this.apiUrl = serviceURL;
    this.apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_OPENAI_API_KEY;
    console.log("Service URL:", this.serviceURL)
    
    
  }

  async sendMessage(message) {
    console.log('API-Key:' + this.apiKey);

    try {
      const apiBody = {
        "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Can you act like you are the Chatbot of the University" +
        "of Heilbronn aka HHN and answer the following prompt and format the message with the respect to only use 100 tokens with the API call: " + message}],
        "max_tokens": 100,
        "temperature": 0,
      }

      console.log(JSON.stringify(apiBody))

      const response = await fetch(this.apiUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.apiKey,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(apiBody),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status} - ${response.statusText}`);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      return data.choices[0].message.content;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return 'Sorry, something went wrong.';
    }
  }
}
```

My web-app component which loads the script

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as Scrivito from "scrivito";
import "./WebChatWidget.scss";




const WebChatWidget = ({ widget }) => {
  const serviceURL = widget.get("serviceURL");
  console.log("Service URL Widget:" , serviceURL)



//Use React Hooks to load external script into scrivito widget
  React.useEffect(() => { 
   
    const cssLink = document.createElement('link'); 
    cssLink.href = "/static/css/main.23941078.css";
    cssLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    document.head.appendChild(cssLink);

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "/static/js/main.14ec3828.js"; 
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    const chunkScript = document.createElement('script');
    chunkScript.src = "/static/js/787.4ed02641.chunk.js"; 
    chunkScript.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(chunkScript);

    meinSkript(serviceURL);
  }, [serviceURL]);

  const meinSkript = (link) => {
    // Verwende den serviceURL in deinem Skript
    console.log(link);
    // ...
  };

  

  return <div id="Chatbot" className="WebChatWidget" style={{ zIndex: 1000 }}></div>;

};



Scrivito.provideComponent("WebChatWidget", WebChatWidget);
```

thank you in advance

I expect the script to load my URL passed from the web-app

Answer (score 1):

In the contents of your `const apiBody = {}`, you need to include a `"url": "https://whateveritmaybe.com"` or a property that contains the link you want to use. When you receive this request, your listener needs to be expecting JSON or parse it specifically for this url you want to utilize in your HTML.